# Debug local APIs from emulator or connected device

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I know that this question is asked really a lot, but none of the answer is working for me.

I'm developing an Android Application on Android Studio, and trying to debug my `.net core` APIs.

I've tried:

- The 10.0.2.2 IP Address
- My local WI-FI IP Address
- Emulator and Connected device are connected to the same WI-FI

So my question is how can I debug my local APIs from an emulator and from my connected device?

Is this still possible on latest updates?

Comment: Did you want to debug .net core apis from your connected android device in visual studio?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want @PerryQian-MSFT

Comment: You should create an android app project on VS and then follow [this link's solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/debug-local-asp-net-core-web-apis-android-emulators/) to debug such local apis from connected device.

Comment: Try running your API in admin mode

Comment: This might be helpful -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zf4iJjnhPzY to debug API requests on your Android device/Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by ignoring ssl error during debugging. This can be done by using different instance of HttpClient as below.

```
#if DEBUG
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            return true;
        };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
#else
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
#endif
```

Also you need to run your api using ip and port instead of localhost.

See "Bypass the certificate security check" section in below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#create-a-development-certificate

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HW_P3Eb-XWU